# How to test servlet filter adding header Spring MVC and zuul proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, netflix-zuul

In the act of passing user identity data on in a process of authenticating a user in a microservice infrastructure I have a filter that I want to test.

When I use Spring's MockMvc then I have not yet found a way to gain access to the **request** headers. It is easy to gain access to the **response** headers like so:

```
@Test
public void WhenSendingRequestThenHeaderAdded() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/health"))
            .andExpect(header().string("X-User-Id", "test"))
            .andReturn();
}
```

In my filter class I add the User's ID and username for downstream consumption. I want to test that in an integration test. I have problems running integration tests with `RestTemplate` and `RestEasy` at the moment because my server uses TLS and I also haven't found a way to run integration tests against my TLS-protected server.

#### Filter class

```
package com.example.gateway.authentication;

import com.example.gateway.users.IUserService;
import com.example.gateway.users.User;
import com.example.gateway.users.UserNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * This filter adds user details for authenticated users to the HTTP Request for downstream consumption.
 */
@Component
public class AddUserInfoFilter implements Filter {

    private IUserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public AddUserInfoFilter(IUserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HeaderMapRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HeaderMapRequestWrapper(req);
        try {
            User user = userService.lookupUser(
                    RequestParser.getUsernameFromHeader(req));
            requestWrapper.addHeader("X-User-Id", String.valueOf(user.getId()));
            requestWrapper.addHeader("X-Username", user.getUsername());
            chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response); // Goes to default servlet.
        } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
            requestWrapper.addHeader("X-User-Id", "-1");
            requestWrapper.addHeader("X-Username", "NOT_AUTHENTICATED");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }

}
```

While this filter properly works I want to write a test that proves that it does.

I also considered using a **Zuul Filter** but didn't get that working.

I am using 
Spring Boot v1.3.1
Spring 4 
Spring Security 4
Zuul 1.0.3

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: Not yet, still looking. I am moving on from Zuul and away from Spring in general, so I may never find an answer.